# How can I print an array's variable name as a string? (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to take the input variable of a function and automate titling the plot as the input variable's name; the commented portions of the code were my attempt but my error reads that since there are multiple values, it is ambiguous. It works if the variable has only one value e.g., an integer or something.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import hilbert, ihilbert

def mod_arg_plot(column, time):

    # title = [i for i, j in locals().items() if j == column][0]

    plt.plot(time, abs(ihilbert(column)), 'b-', time, np.angle(ihilbert(column)), 'r--')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude / degrees')
    plt.legend(('Modulus', 'Argument'))
    # plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
```

error message:

```
line 44, in mod_arg_plot
    title = [i for i, j in locals().items() if j == column][0]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 44, in <listcomp>
    title = [i for i, j in locals().items() if j == column][0]
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Why does the title have multiple values in an array format?

Comment: Is the title a complete sentence?

Comment: No, in my most recent case, 'column' was a single letter. It did however represent a 1001x4 complex array. I updated the post with the error messages

Comment: If you have the title as a name of a local variable, why you would not just give the title as an argument to the `mod_arg_plot` function?

Comment: J is an array and cannot be compared directly with `column`

Comment: An array (or any other python object) does not have a 'name'.  It can be assigned to a variable (or many variables), but that's not the same as having a name.  And trying to use '==' on an array will give you this kind of ambiguity error.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. It does however work if the variable was just an integer, does it then have to do with the array being multi-valued? Also then how would I get around this?